# Why does my http request not have a body after switching to vs 2019 from 2017?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

So I had a project in vs 2017, with a post method in my API controller, it worked just fine and it receives the json body i send from my view. However after recreating the project in vs 2019 it no longer has a request body.

My .NET Core is version 3.1

This is my post request

```
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public void CreateOrder([FromBody] Order data)
        {
            bool _priceBool = false;
            if(data.Price <= 10000)
            {
                _priceBool = true;
            };
            var order = new Order
            {
                Title = data.Title,
                Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                Supplier = data.Supplier,
                Projekt = data.Projekt,
                Department = data.Department,
                Description = "Description rkgmrk r,gpw viuje eobin wueji, ok,wem ue wej iemgke ,lrve efke",
                Price = data.Price,
                Approval = _priceBool,
                Payment = false,
            };

            _db.Order.Add(order);
            _db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

I still face the same problem after sending the request with postman, so i assume its purely the api thats the problem.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit 1: Sorry i forgot to include the error here it is:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This is where i make the request and the header is just a basic json content type
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZoQv.png)

Edit 3: This here is my Order Class:

```
public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Supplier { get; set; }

        public string Projekt { get; set; }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

        public bool Approval { get; set; }

        public bool Payment { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Did you update the version of .NET Core too?

Comment: The return type of the action is void - nothing is returned. What content do you expect to see?

Comment: What is the URL?  Why are you using "[action]" in the route? Can you show the code that makes the request?

Comment: @RyanThomas Hi thanks for the help. My .NET Core is vesion 3.1

Comment: Hi @phuzi, i'm not trying to return anything i just get an error saying data is null when i try to add my order object to my database.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Darkonekt. I am just using postman atm.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's the request body that appears to be empty. Thought you meant the response.

Comment: Can you include a complete example of the JSON being POST'ed?

Comment: Please avoid `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` use always UTC dates when working in the backend

Comment: also place a breakpoint inside your method to see what happens

Comment: Let me see if I understand the problem.... When you use postman and place a breakpoint inside your method... You can actually see the breakpoint being hit... But the Order data parameter is null?

Comment: Also can you please post the Order class... I want to see if the properties match the types coming from JSON

Comment: Hi @Darkonekt, Sorry for the delayed response. But yes the Order data parameter is null. I have also added the order class as an edit.

Comment: it might be nothing but the Price field in your PostMan screen shot looks like a string  inside double quotes.... Can you post it without the double quotes like this "Price":2321

Comment: I am just trying to rule out a difference in the model.  So when a value in JSON is surrounded by double quotes like this "Price":"2321" it means  it is a string. So please try to send the value without the double quotes like this "Price":2312

Comment: Hi @Darkonekt, Thanks for the help. It worked when i removed the double quotes, thank you so much. I just check the 2017 version and i got the double quotes aswell, so i'm not sure why one work and the other doesn't. If you want to make an answer i can mark it as accepted if you want.

Comment: Would you be so kind to mark my answer as correct please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the model has a mismatch property.

The Order class has a property of type int for Price.

But the JSON has that as a string according to the image posted from PostMan.

If you change the property type to string or change the JSON to pass a number ( no quotations in the value ) it should work.